# C | Leer de un archivo una cadena de caracteres y otros tipos de datos e imprimirlos en consola

Tags: c, string, caracteres

Tengo escritos en un archivo algunos datos, como por ejemplo:

**Juanito Perez 15 1161027**

**Maria Antonieta 18 1151025**

= nombre,edad,matricula =

Entonces, el nombre de la persona está escrito siendo una cadena de caracteres, y quiero imprimir en consola los datos que hay dentro de ese archivo, teniendo en cuenta que el nombre es una cadena.

La función que se encargaría de la impresión de tales datos en la consola fue esta:

```
void imprimir()
{
FILE *pf;
char nom[40];
int edad, mat;  
    
pf=fopen("probando.txt","r");

if(pf==NULL)
exit(0);

printf("Datos dentro del archivo: \n");
fscanf(pf,"%s%d%d",nom,&edad,&mat);
while(!feof(pf))
{
    printf("%s %d %d\n",nom,edad,mat);
    fscanf(pf,"%s%d%d",nom,&edad,&mat);
}
fclose(pf);
}
```

El problema radica en que al momento de imprimir los datos, me imprime las cadenas de forma independiente, por ejemplo:

**Mario Bros 15 18892**

Me lo imprime como:

**Datos dentro del archivo:**

**Mario 15 18892**

**Bros 15 18892**

Y debería ser:

**Datos dentro del archivo:**

**Mario Bros 15 18892**

Ósea, todo la cadena de caracteres del nombre debería estar en una sola línea y no separadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que usas el espacio ( ) como separador de datos. Por lo que si el espacio forma parte del registro te separará el registro en varios datos:

```
    Separadores
     |    |  |
     v    v  v
Mario Bros 15 18892
\___/ \__/ \/ \___/
  \     \   \    \____ dato 4
   \     \   \________ dato 3
    \     \___________ dato 2 \_______ son un dato, no dos.
     \________________ dato 1 /
```

Se me ocurren dos soluciones:

1. Usa un separador que no forme parte de los datos, por ejemplo la coma (`,`):

   ```
   FILE *f = fopen("datos.txt", "r");

   if (f) do
   {
       char linea[200];
       fgets(linea, 200, f);

       printf("Leida linea \"%s\" estos son sus datos:\n", linea);
       for (char *token = strtok(linea, ","); token; token = strtok(NULL, ","))
       {
           printf("\tDato: %s\n", token);
       }
   } while (!feof(f));

   fclose(f);
   ```
2. Asumiendo que los nombres de personas nunca contendrán números ([asunción errónea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee)) busca dónde está el primer número y todo lo anterior será nombre:

   ```
   f = fopen("datos.txt", "r");

   printf("\n\n\nBuscando el primer numero:\n");
   if (f) do
   {
       char linea[200];
       fgets(linea, 200, f);

       printf("Leida linea \"%s\" estos son sus datos:\n", linea);
       int longitud = strcspn(linea, "0123456789");
       printf("\tNombre: %.*s\n", longitud, linea);
       for (char *token = strtok(linea + longitud, " "); token; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
       {
           printf("\tDato: %s\n", token);
       }
   } while (!feof(f));

   fclose(f);
   ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVNfb9MwEH9OPsVhhJSUUCWFbNkKSEyABCoTL3uiPHiO3Vqkvsh2GAL1s5eL07UdEhQkEIrkJOe7@/05WzxaCLHZ3NdGNF0t4anztcbx8nl8J9To6x9jVptFH4s/o65BupYLjS5J429x9PrN7BWMFDwDha00Cau5Rzf2XzzLgN2wdBrHkVaQqDSOKD9SLbXzKlEZ/UTsbceN9gjvpZVfoSihKE6KfHI6Nyzsv@NWc3hhPBotPYeiooySMsrDDIQLiy6UV9XZZNgi6GhN6Eo06CQRmMbrrQYnW255jVb@CxlZUWa/lpEVVfZTGaH8mAwChxXXJun1BAl3NE2PSbKDpK0KduW4qREErni/4N6hc2LRtxvEQ42DfrHkFhptJP8wyfOP096ShfQuCbEMKJiBChg7kJnUNR@KYM4euDmjw0ScwKEB1zkIDHvAbMhKQ1u0kAS4kcdP0pAgOpL0eQvFMiIIYW/72qdcXs1mQwbNLRDfsZn7lwR3DsSjBwyFAXBNfsPNUjcSkntKIg05DUIOJhBH@2tANb/p8tz0z0XnRHBbNkA7K2nBdLTif7e6P1QNmoX2XT14KFxrdj7nxeTxk/LktDoLNA@cvMTVtZXk5Xg0uHnb5Q8GCQ8PqhgcnSn8/Zla6TtrIKcbttl8Bw)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el espacio en blanco se usa como separador.
Una solución fácil:
Cambiar `fscanf(pf,"%s%d%d",nom,&edad,&mat);` 
por `fscanf(pf,"%s%s%d%d",nom,ape,&edad,&mat);` 
y agregar `char ape[40];` para almacenar el apellido.
Esto solo funciona cuando tienes **Nombre** y **Apellido** 
si falta uno o agregas otro apellido no funciona, otra
solución es cambiar el formato del nombre, por ejemplo 
*Mario_Bros* y remplazar el *guión bajo* por un *espacio* al imprimir.

Y una solución un poco más complicada, no es la 
más elegante ni la mas eficiente, pero creo que te puede servir, 
no es difícil de entender. Cualquier duda pregunta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATO_NOMBRE    1
#define DATO_EDAD      2
#define DATO_MATRICULA 3

/* Almacena el carácter que sera
 * usado como separador, no se debe
 * usar como parte de los datos. */
int separador = ',';

void imprimir()
{
    FILE *datos;
    char buffer[1024];
    int leido, posicion = 0;
    int dato_actual = DATO_NOMBRE; //El primer dato a imprimir.
    
    if ((datos = fopen("probando.txt", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Datos dentro del archivo: \n");
        
        while (!feof(datos))
        {
            /* Lee carácter por carácter.
             * 
             * La lectura se detiene al encontrar
             * el separador, un salto de línea o
             * cuando se llega al final del archivo. */
            while (((leido = fgetc(datos)) != separador)
            && (leido != '\n') && (leido != EOF))
            {
                buffer[posicion++] = (char)leido;
            }
            
            /* Permite ignorar líneas vaciás
             * o separadores extra. */
            if (posicion > 0)
            {
                /* Añade un carácter nulo al
                 * final de la cadena y restablece
                 * la posición a cero para la siguiente
                 * lectura. */
                buffer[posicion] = '\0';
                posicion = 0;
                
                /* Para controlar que dato se debe
                 * imprimir se usa la variable 'dato_actual'
                 * y, al finalizar, esta variable se actualiza
                 * al siguiente dato, cuando el último
                 * dato es mostrado la variable 'dato_actual'
                 * tiene que reiniciar al primer dato a imprimir
                 * para mantener un ciclo. */
                switch (dato_actual)
                {
                    /* Se puede realizar cualquier acción,
                     * no solo imprimir. */
                    case DATO_NOMBRE:
                        printf("  Nombre:    %s\n", buffer);
                        
                        dato_actual = DATO_EDAD;
                    break;
                    
                    case DATO_EDAD:
                        /* atoi toma una cadena como argumento
                         * y devuelve un entero (int), sí el primer
                         * carácter no es numérico retorna cero. */
                        printf("  Edad:      %d\n", atoi(buffer));
                        
                        dato_actual = DATO_MATRICULA;
                    break;
                    
                    case DATO_MATRICULA:
                        /* Un 'int' puede quedarse pequeño para
                         * representar una matrícula, atol retorna
                         * un 'long'. */
                        printf("  Matrícula: %ld\n\n", atol(buffer));
                        
                        dato_actual = DATO_NOMBRE; //Reiniciar posición.
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            /* Un mensaje que nos dice:
             * «No hay bucle infinito» 
             * Mmmm claro ¡cómo no! */
            if (EOF == leido)
            {
                printf("Lectura finalizada");
                
                /* En este punto se sabe que
                 * se llego al final del archivo
                 * y se puede realizar algunas 
                 * comprobaciones. */
                if (dato_actual > DATO_NOMBRE)
                {
                    printf(", ¡datos insuficientes!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(".\n");
                }
            }
        }
        
        fclose(datos);
    }
}

int main()
{
    imprimir();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Se asume que el archivo tiene un formato especifico:
`nombre` `separador` `edad` `separador` `matrícula` `\n|EOF`